# List of acceptable entries in openbox config (keyboard)

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, openbox

Is there an exhaustive list of the tokens that openbox config xml files recognize for keybindings?  e.g.

- F1 = <kbd>F1</kbd>
- ...
- W = <kbd>Windows</kbd>
- C = <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

I'm specifically interested in how openbox differentiates between the standalone <kbd>Delete</kbd> key and the <kbd>. Del</kbd> key on the number pad (but I would really like that exhaustive list if it exists).

There isn't anything in the openbox man page and apparently [openbox.org](http://openbox.org/) hates me because I keep getting `403 Forbidden` when I try to go there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page you want is [Help:Bindings](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) (accessible in the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140903011117/http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) as the site is currently not working. Similar information is also available in the manual. The recognized modifiers are:

> ```
> S Shift key
> C Control key
> A Alt key
> W Super key (Usually bound to the Windows key on keyboards which have one)
> M Meta key
> H Hyper key (If it is bound to something)
> ```

The key names are the standard X11 key names (keysyms), the same that you can find in the xmodmap or XKB configuration. You can check which keysym a key or key combination sends with the `xev` command: run it in a terminal, type in the xev window and watch the `KeyPress` events. You can find a list of all known keysyms in `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`.

The standalone <kbd>Delete</kbd> sends `Delete`. The keypad ./Del<.kbd> key sends `KP_Delete` or `KP_Decimal` depending on the Num Lock and Shift states.